# Generate a xml file using APEX then forward it to JasperReports

Tags: xml, jasper-reports, datasource, oracle-apex

I use Oracle APEX 4.2 (within Server1), JasperReports 4.6.0 (within server2).
I want to generate a xml file using APEX (it's possible like this example)

```
OWA_UTIL.mime_header ('application/txt', FALSE);
htp.p('Content-Disposition:attachment;filename="'|| v_file_name|| '"');
OWA_UTIL.http_header_close;
htp.p('
<?xml version="1.0" standalone="no"?>
<!DOCTYPE labels SYSTEM "label.dtd">
<labels _FORMAT="' || :p1_p1 || '" >
<label _QUANTITY="'|| :p2_p2 || '" >
<variable name = "OLDPRICE">*12.99*</variable>
<variable name = "NEWPRICE">*9.99*</variable>
<variable name = "SKU">*12345*</variable>
<variable name = "COLOR">*010*</variable>
</label>
</labels>
');
```

Then, I want to forward it to JasperReports server, to be used like XML Data source.

Is it possible to do this?

Thanks in advance.

Best Regards.

Answer (score 0):

you may try the built in restful services of apex 
you can develop a webservice by using pl/sql and the port your jasperreports server to apex
results can be generated in json or csv (in this option you can format the file in plsql and maybe you can format your result as a single result in xml )

SQL Workshop -> RESTful Services

http://www.oracle.com/webfolder/technetwork/tutorials/obe/db/apex/r42/RESTful_WS_oll/RESTful_WS_oll.html